# Maven surefire-report:report-only not able to consolidate parallel run results as one of XML file has time with "," within it

Tags: junit, reporting, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using parallel execution for running tests, and junit is creating multiple XML files with parallel runs. Post which I am supposed to consolidate this results to get a html report. During this if any of the Test*.XML report has the time value like 1,234.34 with comma seperated, it shows the error in the line throwing, "Failed to parse time value".

I tried getting plugin configurations which corrects ot suppresses this.